# How to print list of tuples like table in Haskell

Tags: haskell

i have a list of tuples like:

```
[("3",69.46),("4",38.32),("5",111.67),("9",97.13)]
```

and i want to print this list of tuple like :

```
3  69.46
4  38.32
5  111.67
9  97.13
```

What is the best way to implement this?
(The length of list is dynamic)
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One way would be like this:

```
printList xs = mapM_ (\(a,b) -> putStr a >> putStr ("  " ++ show b) >> putStrLn "") xs
```

Or in a more readable way:

```
printList xs = mapM_ (\(a,b) -> do
                          putStr a
                          putStr ("  " ++ show b)
                          putStrLn "") xs
```

Or as @icktoofay points out you can use a single `putStrLn`:

```
printList xs  = mapM_ (\(a,b) -> putStrLn $ a ++ " " ++ show b) xs
```

In ghci:

```
λ> printList [("3",69.46),("4",38.32),("5",111.67),("9",97.13)]
3  69.46  
4  38.32  
5  111.67  
9  97.13
```

Comment: +1, but I'd make it point free and use do-notation: `mapM_ $ \(a,b) -> do ...`

Comment: @nomen Included a do-notation based code. pointfree tool gives me this: `mapM_ (uncurry (flip flip putStrLn . ((>>) .) . (. (putStr . flip (++) . show)) . (>>) . putStr)) xs` And I find that hardly readable.

Comment: yeah, that's too much.  I just meant getting rid of the argument to `printList`.

Comment: Why not use `putStr` only once, e.g. `printList = mapM_ $ \(a,b) -> putStrLn $ a ++ "  " ++ show b`?

Comment: @icktoofay Yes, that's much simpler. Updated it.